# Rails - best database design for existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have inherited some Rails 4 code and database models which I need to add to.

The model, called `mpb_item` has a table called `mpb_items`.

Inside this items table there are columns such as:

```
role1_start_date, role2_start_date, role3_start_date, role4_start_date
```

Not ideal but this is what it is.  They should have been in a separate roles table I guess.

I need to add functionality to Suspend any one of these roles (or all of them).

I guess I can either:

1. To the existing table, I can add a new boolean column for each existing role column. e.g. `role1_suspended`, `role2_suspended` etc
2. Create table called `mpb_suspensions`, with 2 columns: `mpb_item_id` and `role_name`.  Since the roles don't have ids themselves, the role_name column will store 'role1', or 'role2' etc depending on which role was suspended.

In my `View`, I need to have the ability to "suspend" each job, or all of them.  I'm not sure how the model code would look to do this and which approach would be best.

Comment: Can you post the model and its associations? What do you mean by design? You need RDB with Rails (SQLite3, MySQL, PostgreSQL, with the last the most powerful with lots of data). When you say inherit, do you mean you are taking on legacy code or someone else's project?

Comment: Any reason you can't create a proper role model (hah) and migrate the data from the `mpb_item` table inside a migration?

Comment: someone elses project its been about for a year or so.  I'm not sure if we could pull the data from mpb_item, as that would then generate a new row   for every role, how would that work?  It would good to write 'mpb_item.role.suspend'  I can't post code at the minute since I'm at home just now...

Comment: and if we pulled the roles into its own table then in the current mpb_items table, the mpb_items.id would no longer be unique as there would be several rows (due to role_id).  Currently there is only one mpb_item per row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I had to build this, given the minimal info you provided I'd start by picking option 2 that you described. (a RoleSuspension is its own table) Benefits include:

- fewer new columns total, and doesn't make any table indefinitely large
- no redundant columns (role1, role2, etc.)
- no need to add more columns if the # of possible roles changes (ie. it's more normalized)
- no nil values (approach 1)
- you can easily query for the overall state of RoleSuspensions (whereas with approach 1 you'd need to count the non-nil values in role1_suspended, role2_suspended, etc. then sum them up), and easier to index
- you can attach logic to a RoleSuspension; it's a separate animal from its parent MbpItem. If it's just a bunch of boolean columns, any complex logic would need to be mushed into the MbpItem model, and would likely be much messier to maintain.

Following option 2's logic, suspending a role would involve creating a new record like this:

```
@mbp_item.role_suspensions.create!(role_number: 2)
```

and checking for suspension status would involve something like this:

```
if @mbp_item.role_suspensions.any?
# or....
RoleSuspension.where(role_number: 3).each do |s|
  puts "Item #{s.mbp_item} is suspended for role #{s.role_number}."
end
```

Database performance will be a larger consideration with this approach, depending on the answers to the following questions:

- Where and how often do you need to check for role suspensions?
- When you check for role suspensions, how do you approach asking the question? In other words is some global task asking "What role suspensions exist, and for what mbp_items?" or do you check for suspensions on a given `mbp_item` when you render that object?

If you'll need to check for role suspensions very frequently, perhaps you should add a boolean column to `mbp_items` called `has_suspensions`, which will be a partial cache in that it will indicate whether any suspensions exist for this MbpItem (and must be maintained in `after_create` and `after_destroy` hooks).

On the other hand, if you **know** that suspension info never will need to have its own logic and never will need to be queried directly, you could add a **single** column to MbpItem, `role_suspensions`, containing a serialized array of integers for the suspended roles. This would be a much less invasive approach in terms of database structure, and probably much simpler even than your option 1 in that it would allow you to suspend and de-suspend any role number with less code and less metaprogramming, but if you ever need to add any fancy logic to the suspension or desuspension process (ie. if a RoleSuspension deserves status as its own object), you'd regret this approach.

Comment: Great answer. We will check suspensions on a given MpbItem, it won't be very regular.  When a user loads a MpbItem, on the View screen it shows each role and if it is suspended or not.  In your create! code, where are role numbers stored?  We don't store ids currently, could use Constants?

Comment: Cool. If it's not something that will be frequently retrieved, I imagine the new-table approach would work fine in terms of database performance.